# GEO station keeping in GMAT

Tags: geostationary, gmat

I am currently trying to implement station keeping maneuvers for a geosynchronous satellite in orbit around Earth using the General Mission Analysis Tool (GMAT) but I am not managing.

I know there are 2 main maneuvers: East-West to correct longitude drift, and North-South to correct inclination but I am not managing to implement these in GMAT.

I have reviewed GMAT's documentation and seen followed the code example for LEO station keeping, which is provided in the samples folder when downloading GMAT, but this deals with altitude station keeping as it is a LEO orbit.

I have also followed an STK tutorial: for maintaining GEO orbit, but am having trouble translating the logic into GMAT's mission section.

Any help or insight provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately the last time a GMAT-tagged question was answered was in August 2022.  If you do find an answer, please let us know; we could use more GMAT-knowledgeable folks here.

Comment: It highly depends on your satellite and mission (chemical or electric propulsion). You should precisely follow the finite or impulsive burn methods for your specific mission. As far as I know @ChrisR has very high knowledge on GMAT.

Comment: You may follow this https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17661/change-of-inclination-using-low-thrust/53915#53915 to learn about more N/S GEO maneuvers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into this.